# Determinant of walk matrix for a skew-symmetric matrix of even order

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $S=(s_{ij})$ be a skew-symmetric integral matrix of order $n$. We only consider the case that $n$ is even. Let $e$ be the all-one vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define the walk matrix $$W(S)=[e,Se,\cdots,S^{n-1}e].$$ (the name "walk matrix" comes from graph theory, where $S$ is the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph. Of course, $S$ is not skew-symmetric in the setting of graphs.)

It is well-known that $\det(S)$ is always a square number. I find that the integer $\sqrt{\det(S)}$ is always a divisor of $\det W(S)$. But I cannot find any references on this relation.

For example, consider $$S=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 4 & 0 & -3 \\
 -4 & 0 & -2 & -1 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
 3 & 1 & -3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$ Then, $$W(S)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & -31 & -3 \\
 1 & -7 & -15 & 165 \\
 1 & 5 & -11 & -87 \\
 1 & 1 & -19 & -75 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
Using Mathematica, we find that $\det(S)=18^2$, $\det(W)=16128=18\times 896$ and $\sqrt{\det(S)}\mid \det(W)$.

It seems that the above relation $\sqrt{\det(S)}\mid \det(W)$ always hold for any skew-symmetric integral matrix of even orders. In particular, when $\det(S)=0$ then $\det(W)=0$. This particular case is not hard to show.

Comment: "In particular, when $\det(S)=0$ then $\det(W)=0$. This particular case is not hard to show." If you can prove that $\operatorname{Pf} S = 0$ implies $\det W = 0$ over an arbitrary commutative ring, then you have solved your problem. Do you use the field property somewhere?

Comment: Actually, it is sufficient to prove that $\operatorname{Pf} S = 0$ implies $\det W = 0$ over any field, since the Pfaffian is a primitive irreducible polynomial over the integers (at least I believe so). Maybe it is even sufficient to restrict oneself to characteristic-$0$ fields.

Comment: Actually, if I am understanding things right, $e$ can be any vector, not necessarily the all-ones vector.

Comment: @darij The commutative algebra approach from your first comment won’t work, otherwise you would prove $\det S\mid \det W$ which may fail (as in the OP’s example).

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: Note that I wrote $\operatorname{Pf}$, not $\det$. But this is moot anyway, as your answer appears to be much better (will read it later tonight).

Comment: @darij Ah, I see. Anyway, in fact, I would be glad to see something more conceptual and connected with the Pfaffian than my answer...

Comment: @darij, det S=0 implies S has 0 as a multiple eigenvalue. Since rank W is at most the number of distinct eigenvalues of S (using the spectral decomposition theorem for normal matrices) .  This fact may imply the division relation as you comment.  I know little about commutative algebra, and I will try your approach.  I recall similar argument can be used to give an interesting (unusual) proof for  Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: @W.Wang: Ah, I see. You can actually argue a bit simpler: Over a field, $\det S = 0$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{Pf} S = 0$ and implies that $S$ has rank $\leq n-2$ (since the rank of an alternating matrix over a field is always even). Hence, for any vector $w$, the $n-1$ vectors $S^1 w, S^2 w, \ldots, S^{n-1} w$ are $n-1$ vectors in a space of dimension $\leq n-2$ (viz., the column space of $S$), and therefore are linearly independent. Hence, the columns of $W$ are linearly dependent, so that $\det W = 0$. Now, ...

Comment: ... by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz (and using the irreducibility of the Pfaffian, which I believe is well-known), this entails that the Pfaffian of $S$ divides the determinant of $W$ as a polynomial over the prime field, which we can take to be $\mathbb{Q}$. Finally, this results in a divisibility over $\mathbb{Z}$ by Gauss's lemma.

Comment: @darij:Now, I understand your approach. It is also very cool,  and is more conceptual( borrowing the language of IIya Bogdanov.)

Comment: @darij Thanks a lot! Could you put this as another answer?

Comment: @darij BTW you don't need irreducibility; you obly beed that the Pfaffian has no multiple irreducible  factors (still I don't know whether it is easier to prove)

Comment: (Sorry for multiple comments) the Pfaffian has no multiple factors merely because it is linear in each variable.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: Your answer is beautiful; I don't see much of a point in adding my own, particularly as I'd have to prove or source some commutative algebra (I'm not sure how easy your criterion for no multiple factors is to prove).

Comment: @darij As for criterion: Apply your argument to each irreducible factor separately. As for reasoms to put an alternative proof: this is kind of technique which is widely applicable, and it replaces some art with more routine actions; I think this may be quite jnstructive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely, there is nothing special in the all-ones vector: the claim holds for any integer-valued $e$.

Notice that
$$
  \det W^TW
  =\det\bigl[e^T (-1)^iS^{i+j}e\bigr],
$$
Since $S$ is skew-symmetric, we have $e^TS^ie=0$ for all odd $i$. Permuting now the rows and columns of $W^TW$ we get
$$
  \det W^TW=\det\begin{bmatrix} A_0&0\\ 0& -A_1\end{bmatrix},
$$
where
$$
  A_0= \begin{bmatrix} 
    e^Te& e^TS^2e& e^TS^4e& \cdots& e^TS^{n-2}e\\
    e^TS^2e& e^TS^4e& e^TS^6e& \cdots& e^TS^ne\\
    \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots& \vdots\\
      e^TS^{n-2}e& e^TS^ne& e^TS^{n+2}e& \cdots& e^TS^{2n-4}e
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
    A_1= \begin{bmatrix} 
    e^TS^2e& e^TS^4e& e^TS^6e& \cdots& e^TS^ne\\
    e^TS^4e& e^TS^6e& e^TS^8e& \cdots& e^TS^{n+2}e\\
    \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots& \vdots\\
      e^TS^{n}e& e^TS^{n+2}e& e^TS^{n+4}e& \cdots& e^TS^{2n-2}e
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We show that
$$
  \det A_1=\pm\det S\det A_0, \qquad(*)
$$
so that $\det W=\pm\det A_0\sqrt{\det S}$, which yields what we want.

Denote
$$
  u_i= \begin{bmatrix} 
    e^TS^ie& e^TS^{i+2}e& \cdots& e^TS^{i+n-2}e
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$
The eigenvalues of $S$ are purely imaginary, so by Cayley—Hamilton we get
$$
  S^{n}=\sum_{j=0}^{n/2-1} \alpha_jS^{2j},
$$
where $\alpha_0=-\det S$.
Therefore,
$$
  u_n= -\det S\, u_0+\sum_{j=1}^{n/2-1} \alpha_ju_{2j}.
$$
Plug this into $\det A_1$, expand by linearity, and erase vanishing summands to get $(*)$.

Comment: Interesting ! this gives another proof that $\det S$ is a square. I liked to teach the Pfaffian, but the students always asked skeptically : "A quoi ça sert ?"

Comment: This proof is very beautiful. Thank you very much,  Bogdanov.  And, as Serre point out, it gives another proof that det S is a square (At least when A_0 is nonsigular for some vector e).

Comment: NB: You don't need the eigenvalues. It suffices to notice that any alternating matrix of odd size has determinant $0$ (an easy property, much easier than the existence of the Pfaffian), and thus the corresponding coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $S$ are zero (being sums of principal minors of odd size).

Comment: @darij Yes I know; eigenvalues were just the first argument which came to my mind. However, they are equally simple (if you regard the matrix as a skew-Hermitian operator).